# Memcheck reports unitialised values when accessing local variables down the stack

Tags: false-positive, memcheck

I encountered a problem that Memcheck reports uninitialized values and I think these are perfectly legal. I managed to create a small example program that exhibits this behavior. I would like to know if Memcheck is really wrong and what can be done about it. (Is there any solution besides adding the errors into a suppression file?)

To reproduce this, I made the program below. It runs function `go` that puts `0x42` on the stack, calls `og` (this pushes the address of the next instruction `leave` on the stack), then in `og` it stores `esp+4` into global variable `a`.

The stack looks like this:

```
| address of `leave` instruction |                     pc = a[-1]
| 0x42                           |  a points here, answer = a[0]
```

If I build it and run Valgrind,

```
gcc -g -m32 main.c go.S -o main
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./main
```

Valgrind thinks that the value in variable `pc` (and `answer`, if you put it in the `if` instead) is undefined. I checked with debugger that the values there actually are what I wanted.

```
==14160== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14160== Command: ./main
==14160== 
==14160== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14160==    at 0x804847D: print (main.c:18)
==14160==    by 0x80484B0: ??? (go.S:19)
==14160==    by 0x8048440: main (main.c:8)
==14160==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14160==    at 0x80484AC: ??? (go.S:19)
==14160== 
==14160== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==14160==    at 0x80484B1: ??? (go.S:20)
==14160==    by 0x8048440: main (main.c:8)
==14160==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14160==    at 0x80484AC: ??? (go.S:19)
```

If I debug from Valgrind with `--vgdb-error=0` and print the definedness, it says that all the bits are undefined.

```
(gdb) p &pc
$1 = (int *) 0xfea5e4a8
(gdb) mo xb 0xfea5e4a8 4
              ff      ff      ff      ff
0xFEA5E4A8:     0x9e    0x84    0x04    0x08
```

The value at 0xfea5e4a8 is

```
(gdb) x/x 0xfea5e4a8
0xfea5e4a8:     0x0804849e
```

and

```
(gdb) x/i 0x0804849e
   0x804849e <go+10>:   leave  
(gdb)
```

## main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *a;

extern void go();

int main() {
    go();
    printf("finito\n");
    return 0;
}

int print() {
    int answer = a[0];
    int pc = a[-1];

    // use the vars
    if (pc == 0x42) {
        printf("%d\n", 0);
    }
}
```

## go.S

```
    .text

.globl go

go:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    pushl $0x42
    call og

    leave
    ret

og:
    addl $4, %esp
    movl %esp, a
    sub $4, %esp
    call print
    ret
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that as soon as you do `addl $4, %esp` you no longer own the part of the stack beyond esp. That's always the case. Though it rarely happens, the O/S is free to overwrite that part of the stack, say in an interrupt handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this sequence of code:

```
addl $4, %esp
movl %esp, a
sub $4, %esp
```

When you move `%esp` up valgrind will mark everything below the new stack pointer position as undefined, and it will stay that way even after you move it back.

It's not safe anyway, because if a signal hit between the add and sub then that stack really might get overwritten (in 32 bit code - in 64 bit code there is a "red zone" below the pointer that is safe but valgrind knows about that).